# MatrixLayout placing UI element in a specific cell

Tags: user-interface, abap, webdynpro

I'm working on a WebDynpro in SAP right now and I need to place a few UI elements in the right side of the WD and the rest on the left side for example.

I know how to group elements but I don't know how to place them to the right side of the screen. I thought about the MatrixLayout and put the elements into a specific cell. But I can't find out where to selected in which cell the elements should be placed.

To sum it up:

"How can I place UI elements in a WD on the right side of the screen and other elements on the left side?"

Does it work with the MatrixLayout, and how?

Should I use something else than the MatrixLayout?

I'm very thankful for every hint :)

Comment: Have you tried to nest transparent containers?

Comment: I just got a familiar answer in a [SAP Forum](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3872860). So I'm trying to use the transparent container and the align attribute. Thank you! ;)